# HeroKu, how to set up the time period before a Dyno become idle and sleep caused by no request coming

Tags: heroku, sleep, dyno

Hey My question is simple. By default, a heroki dyno goes sleep when in 30 mins no request coming. I want this period reduced to 10 mins. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official answer I've got from `Heroku` support: `This is a platform wide setting so it isn't configurable at the moment.`